# After IIS 8 Install on a Windows 2012 Server C:\inetpub\Adminscript folder is missing.

Tags: iis-8

I am unable to see  C:\inetpub\Adminscript folder in a windows 2012 server, after installing IIS8 Feuture.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-iis-7/understanding-setup-in-iis

They are in "IIS 6 Scripting Tools". Enable that and you will see the folder.